# Editing a ListView item returns "Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList. " if the FormView is in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu, formview

I have a FormView and a ListView that I would like to live only inside the FormView's EditITemTemplate.  However, any time I click an Edit or Update LinkButton in the ListView (with the FOrmView in Edit Mode) the page errors with: "Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList."  As you can see below, I have removed the ListView from the FormView completely, and the ListView functions as intended if the FormView is in ReadOnly.

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RTUConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT *, '' LogInput FROM [nei_list] WHERE [nei_id]=@ID">
                <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlNEIT" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RTUConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT ID TID, CLLI, EquipmentType, Officecode, OfficeName, WorkingLines, Testable Tstbl FROM NEI_Testable WHERE CLLI=@ID ORDER BY [EquipmentType], OfficeCode"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE NEI_Testable SET Testable = @Tstbl WHERE ID=@TID"
            >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Tstbl" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TID" Type="String" />

            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlSource" DefaultMode="ReadOnly">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr style="font-size:large; background-color: #006600; color: #FFFFFF;">
                        <td style="padding: 2px" align="center"></b></td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px" colspan="5" align="left"><b>NEI Maintenance and Inventory Log</b></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>Location ID:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Textbox ID="txtLocID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location_ID") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>Location Name:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Textbox ID="txtLocName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LOCATION_NAME") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>NET_LOC_TYPE_ID:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Textbox ID="txtNETLOC" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NET_LOC_TYPE_ID") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>Host:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Textbox ID="txtHOST" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MAIN_ID") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>EXCH AREA CLLI:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Textbox ID="txtEXCH" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EXCHANGE_AREA_CLLI") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>OP CO NUM:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Textbox ID="txtOPCO" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OPERATING_COMPANY_NUMBER") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B></B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#E8E8E8; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>System:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>Testable:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#E8E8E8; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>RTU:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>EXT:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#E8E8E8; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>NEI:</B></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #CEF6CE;color: #284775; "></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; ">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSys" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("system") %>' Enabled="True" >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AC" Selected="True">AC</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="OSG" Selected="True">OSG</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #CEF6CE;color: #284775; ">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTst" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("testable") %>' Enabled="True" >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="YES" Selected="True">YES</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NO" Selected="True">NO</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; ">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRTU" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("RTU") %>' Enabled="True" >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="YES" Selected="True">YES</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NO" Selected="True">NO</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #CEF6CE;color: #284775; ">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEXT" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("EXT") %>' Enabled="True" >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="YES" Selected="True">YES</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NO" Selected="True">NO</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; ">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNEI" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("NEI") %>' Enabled="True" >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="YES" Selected="True">YES</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NO" Selected="True">NO</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; text-align:center"><B>*<%#Request.Cookies["RTUA"]["NAME"].ToString() %>*<br />*<%#DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy h:mmtt") %>*</B></td>
                    <td colspan="5" style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775;"><asp:Textbox ID="txtREMARKS" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LogInput") %>'  Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%" /></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr style="font-size:large; background-color: #006600; color: #FFFFFF;">
                        <td style="padding: 2px" align="center"><b><asp:button id="UpdateButton"  CausesValidation="True" text="Update" commandname="Update" runat="server" ForeColor="#003300"/> </b></td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px" colspan="5" align="left"><b></b></td></tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr style="font-size:large; background-color: #006600; color: #FFFFFF;">
                        <td style="padding: 2px" align="center"><b><asp:button id="EditButton" text="EDIT" commandname="Edit" runat="server" ForeColor="#003300"/> </b></td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px" colspan="5" align="left"><b>NEI Maintenance and Inventory Log</b></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>Location ID:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Label ID="lblLocID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location_ID") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>Location Name:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Label ID="lblLocName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LOCATION_NAME") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>NET_LOC_TYPE_ID:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Textbox ID="lblNETLOC" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NET_LOC_TYPE_ID") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>Host:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Label ID="lblHOST" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MAIN_ID") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>EXCH AREA CLLI:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Label ID="lblEXCH" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EXCHANGE_AREA_CLLI") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="font-size:small; background-color:#CEF6CE; color: #333333; width: 130px;"><B>OP CO NUM:</B></td>
                    <td style="font-size:medium; background-color: #E8E8E8;color: #284775; "><asp:Label ID="lblOPCO" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OPERATING_COMPANY_NUMBER") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
                </Table>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:FormView>


                    <asp:ListView ID="lvNEIT" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlNEIT">                       
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr style="font-size:small; background-color: #FFFFFF;color: #284775;">
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEIID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TID") %>' Visible="false" />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEIEQT" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EquipmentType") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEION" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OfficeName") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEIOC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OfficeCode") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEIWL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WorkingLines") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNEITST" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Tstbl") %>' Enabled="False" >
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="YES" Selected="True">YES</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="NO" Selected="True">NO</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="UNK" Selected="True">UNK</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnNEIEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>                                
                        <tr style="font-size:small; background-color: #FFFFFF;color: #284775;">
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEIID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TID") %>' Visible="false" />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEIEQT" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EquipmentType") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEION" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OfficeName") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEIOC" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OfficeCode") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNEIWL" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WorkingLines") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNEITST" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Tstbl") %>' Enabled="True" >
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="YES" Selected="True">YES</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="NO" Selected="True">NO</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="UNK" Selected="True">UNK</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnNEISave" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <table width="98%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" runat="server">
                            <tr align="center" runat="server">
                                <td runat="server">
                                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">

                        <tr></tr>
                            <tr runat="server" style="font-size:small; background-color:#006600; color: #FFFFFF;">
                                <th runat="server"></th>
                                <th runat="server">EquipmentType</th>
                                <th runat="server">OfficeName</th>
                                <th runat="server">OfficeCode</th>
                                <th runat="server">WorkingLines</th>
                                <th runat="server">Testable</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single one of my ListItem's contained Selected="True".  Removed that and everything works perfectly.

Seems like that silly mistake would have caused the page to fail on the very first binding event, rather than only happening when both the FormView and ListView were in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ListBox control instead of dropdownlist

```
       <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="ddlSys" SelectionMode="multiple">
       <asp:ListItem Value="AC" Selected="True">AC</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="OSG" Selected="True">OSG</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: Why ListBox?  It should be an either or option, so SelectionMode="multiple" is wrong.  Also, the ddlSys you chose to swap out is in the FormView, which works fine on it's own.  It's the ListView components that cause the error.  And that selection should also be an either or option.

Comment: Ok, I get it.  Those were supposed to be one item selections all along, set by the SelectedValue='<%# Bind("system") %>'.  Thanks for drawing my attention to it.